# Change default axis2 Webservice call from Websphere?

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, cxf, apache-axis

Hi, I want to call webservice using `cxf`, for that i have added all cxf related jars to project build path while coding. While deploying in websphere added all jars in SupportingJars folder and set it Reference Shared Libraries of my ear.

Please find below code to call webservice

`Dispatch disp = service.createDispatch( portName, jaxbContext,Service.Mode.PAYLOAD );
   Object jaxbResObject = (Object) disp.invoke( jaxbReqObject );`

This code is working fine in Weblogic as **org.apache.cxf.jaxws.DispatchImpl** disp object. But in webshpere it is returning **org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.dispatch.JAXBDispatch**  as disp object and getting
`javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException` from axis2 while `invoke`

I come to know like websphere plugin folder contains axis2 jars. As default `createDispatch` method of javax using this jar. How can i change class loading policy or say javax createDispatch to use my `cxf jars in ref shared lib folder ??`

Comment: For CXF you need disable annotation scanning and change classloader. Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26768877/3701228) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Gas. Thing is that i'm calling webservice from ejb jar, it also contains some utility methods used by other components of EAR. Now how can i set parent last option for EJB jar ??

Comment: Try to set parent last on the application level then.

Comment: EAR not starting :-(

Comment: What error do you have?

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere Application Server uses Axis2 based web service engine, when you want to use CXF, please follow this documentation to disable the Axis2 engine to avoid any Jar conflict issue.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html?lang=en

Regards
Yang